# LINQ SUM, AVERAGE

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, linq

This is code that returns list of data from Splatt Table.

```
Public Function GetListofProduct(ByVal pCOde As String, ByVal date1 As DateTime, ByVal date2 As DateTime) As List(Of Splatt)
   Return (From e As Splatt In TradingCTX.Splatts Where e.plCode.Contains(pCOde) And (e.plDate = date1 Or e.plDate = date2)).ToList
End Function
```

I really need help about getting the sum of the price and transfer it to another gridview.[image: IMAGE 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing the Linq the way you are try like this. This will give you the sum, but you can also return your list by calling `ToList()` instead of `Sum`. You can also use `Average`.

```
Dim sum As Double = TradingCTX.Splatts.Where(Function(e) e.plCode.Contains(pCOde) And (e.plDate = date1 Or e.plDate = date2)).Sum(Function(e) e.Charges)
```

There is nothing wrong with writing the Linq as you have so you could keep your Linq and just change your `ToList()` to `.Sum(Function(e) e.Charges)` where `e.Charges` is the name of the field you want to sum.

Please explain your difficulties getting the sum value to another table.